# Loop through array of dictionaries in AJAX

Tags: jquery

I am looking to update a dataTable using Ajax on my application. I get it to work, except for a column that contains an array of dictionaries. The goal is to retrieve the value for each key in each dictionary. The code I code I wrote so far is:

```js
$ ->
  $('#activities-datatable').dataTable
    processing: true
    order: []
    serverSide: true
    ajax: url: $('#activities-datatable').data('source')
    pagingType: 'full_numbers'
    columns: [
      { data: 'id' }
      { data: 'first_name' }
      { data: 'last_name' }
      {
        data: 'activities',
        render: (data) ->
          for var key in data ) {
            var value = obj[value];
          }
      }
      { data: 'city' }
    ]
    columnDefs: [
      { 
        orderable: false, 
        targets: 0 
      }
    ]
```

I think i am not far but something is not right obviously since no result comes out.
Can someone guide me please ?

Comment: Can you please update the question to include an example of the response to the AJAX request

Comment: Do check the console for errors as you have a syntax error, but it might just be from creating the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m it is actually from creating the question, If you remove the render part, it works fine. But it display to me the entire array. [{"act1" => "swim}, {"act2 => "run"}, etc]